# Include Today's Date in Lead Time SQL query

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to get the max date differences using LEAD for each row in the following sql query and then ordering it in descending order. Below is the query and its results. What I want to be able to do is also include the current date. Currently I can't include the difference between the last recorded incident and today's date.

So in my desired result, the lead date would be the today's date (it's null in the current results query non ordered). Currently as it stands, the last recorded incident was 5/12/2016 so that would mean the difference between the last recorded incident and today's date is something like 63ish days.

USING SQL SERVER

**Query:**

```
 Select 
 convert(varchar, CLL.Call_Log_Date, 101) as [CreatedDate], 
 convert(varchar, Lead(CLL.Call_Log_Date, 1) 
           Over (Order by CLL.Call_Log_Date DESC), 101) as [Lead],
 DATEDIFF(dd, Lead(CLL.Call_Log_Date, 1) 
          Over (Order by CLL.Call_Log_Date DESC ), CLL.Call_Log_Date) as [DIFF]
 From VMWareSM_Test.dbo.RV_CALL as CLL 
 Where CLL.IPK_Status_Ref = '1' 
 And CLL.Call_Priority_Ref IN (6,7)
 Order by [DIFF] DESC;
```

**Result**

```
CreatedDate           Lead             DIFF
06/24/2015         05/12/2015          43
11/20/2015         10/09/2015          42
05/13/2016         04/08/2016          35
10/09/2015         09/14/2015          25
01/13/2015         12/23/2014          21
12/22/2014         12/03/2014          19
01/08/2016         12/21/2015          18
03/02/2015         02/12/2015          18
08/23/2015         08/07/2015          16
04/08/2016         03/25/2016          14
```

Comment: just use `GETDATE()`. Also, please, always give an explicit length when converting to varchar: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CLL.Call_Log_Date, 101)`

Comment: Is it simply insert the GetDate()? And I apologize. I'm rather new to SQL.

Comment: Just replace `Lead(.....` with `GETDATE()`

Comment: are you wanting to replace the null value with today's date?.. if so you can use    `coalesce(Lead(CLL.Call_Log_Date, 1) Over (Order by CLL.Call_Log_Date DESC), GetDate())`

Comment: @JamieD77 as I understood it, op needs to actually always use `GETDATE`

Comment: @Lamak  `currently I can't include the difference between the last recorded incident and today's date.`.. sounds like he's just asking about the latest.. which would not have a LEAD

Comment: @JamieD77 yes, that's how I see it, and why I said that op should just replace `LEAD(...` with `GETDATE()`

Comment: Both of these are correct. I shouldn't be using LEAD, but instead LAG and also using coalesce. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Coalesce to replace the NULL value with today's date.

```
Select 
     convert(varchar, CLL.Call_Log_Date, 101) as [CreatedDate], 
     convert(varchar, Coalesce(Lead(CLL.Call_Log_Date, 1) 
           Over (Order by CLL.Call_Log_Date DESC), GetDate()), 101) as [Lead],
     DATEDIFF(dd, Coalesce(Lead(CLL.Call_Log_Date, 1) 
          Over (Order by CLL.Call_Log_Date DESC ), GetDate()), CLL.Call_Log_Date) as [DIFF]
 From VMWareSM_Test.dbo.RV_CALL as CLL 
 Where CLL.IPK_Status_Ref = '1' 
 And CLL.Call_Priority_Ref IN (6,7)
 Order by [DIFF] DESC;
```